# Prove a divisibility property in $\Bbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory

I am stuck on how to prove the following question:

> Let $a,b,d \in \mathbb Z$. Now suppose that $d\mid ab$. Prove that there exists $e,f \in \mathbb Z$ such that $d=ef$ and $e\mid a$ and $f\mid b$.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $e=\gcd(d,a)$; by definition this is a factor of $d$ and so $d=ef$ for some $f$.  It is also true by definition that $e\mid a$, so it remains to show that $f\mid b$.

We have $ef\mid ab$ so
$$f\ \Big|\ \frac aeb\ ;$$
also
$$\gcd\Bigl(f,\frac ae\Bigr)=\gcd\Bigl(\frac de,\frac ae\Bigr)
  =\frac1e\gcd(d,a)=1\ ;$$
and so
$$f\mid b$$
as required.

Comment: yes, this make complete sense! I didn't think to take $e$ as being the $gcd(d,a)$. Thanks for your help and time :)